# Do I need to do a MySQL password reset and if so, how do I locate the init.d file?

Tags: mysql, passwords, reset, init.d, locate

I'm tring to learn some MySQL to set up a database and one of the steps is:

mysql -u root --password=9898

It gives me this :

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I don't think I'm using the wrong password but ok, I guess I need to reset the password.
Is there another possibility?

I found a link on Stackoverflow http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/recover-mysql-root-password.html with some instructions so I could do a reset but I'm stuck again.
I need to locate the init.d file but I don't know how.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Belongs on superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes MySQL can be fussy with spacing and extra characters. Does this work?

```
mysql -uroot -p9898
```

Regardless, you can always add an [inti_file](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_init-file) to your `my.cnf` which contains a single line, something like

```
   GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '9898' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

and restart your MySQL service.

Comment: Thank you but both didn't work. I deleted mysql en reinstalled it, but I'm having the exact same problem. When I'm trying to set up the password, it gives me the same error. How's that even possible? It's not a mysql upgrade, I deleted mysql. The only thing I can think of is that I'm not deleting it the way I should. Is there more to it than right click and delete ?